# Trino Postgres connector behavior

Tags: postgresql, trino

I would like to run queries on Yugabyte (ysql - it is a distributed db) VIA Trino, by Trino docs I need to use Postgres connector.
Th problem is that i got a bad performance (by far) when I run query on Yuga via Trino than I run it directly on Yuga.

My question - is it true that Trino has one thread to Postgres connector, meaning that I can connect only to one host and can not connect to more than one host? (since Yuga is a distributed db - is has more than one host so the query performance very fast but seems that Trino can not connect to more than one host)

Thanks!

I have created values.yaml and play with the url connection, even if I added 2 hosts, the performance was the same...